# Jinja2 - If condition & nested array

Tags: arrays, if-statement, ansible, jinja2

I'd like to build to simple `if` logic into my Jinja2 template with nested arrays.

Firstly, including my vars for reference.

In YML (from host_vars):

```
interfaces:
    - name: ae10
      ipv4:
        - address: 4.4.4.4
          mask: 8
```

in JSON (from Ansible debug):

```
"interfaces": [
    {
        "ipv4": [
            {
                "address": "4.4.4.4",
                "mask": 8
            }
        ],
        "name": "ae10"
    }
],
```

I would like the `if` statement to make sure that `ipv4.address` and `ipv4.mask` have values. The only way I seem to be able to do it at the moment, is to map the nested array first, and then run if statement. But I'm wondering if the `if` statement can be ran earlier? Like even before the `for` loop starts?

```
{%for interface in interfaces%}
    {%for ip in interface.ipv4%}
        {% if ip.address and ip.mask%}
            matched {{ip.address}}/{{ip.mask}} on {{interface.name}}
        {% else %}
            nothing matched
        {% endif %}
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

It might, or might not be possible - and I might be missing something silly. Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you misprint `interfeces` which is in JSON sample with `interface` which is in jinja2 template.

Comment: I don’t see any issues there Sergei? `interface` variable in jinja2 template is set for every array under `interfaces`. So effectively all variables under `ae10` array would be mapped to `interface.variable`, such as `interface.name`. If we added another array, such as `ae20`, same would apply to that. Also, `interface` is just a word - I could have picked any other word such as `interface_variable` or even `car`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I had added my comment before you edited your post and added enclosing loop over the `interfaces` array. Now everything looks ok.

Comment: > But I'm wondering if the if statement can be ran earlier? Like even before the for loop starts?
Your current implementation looks pretty good. But what way do you want to change it? Which `for` loop you want to omit and why?

Answer (score 0):

> Q: "Can the if statement be run earlier? Like even before the for loop starts?"

A: No. It's not possible. It's possible to omit items that don't comply with the conditions, create a new dictionary, and process the new dictionary.

The task below is testing in the loop

```
- debug:
    msg: "matched {{ item.1.address }}/{{ item.1.mask }} on {{ item.0.name }}"
  loop: "{{ interfaces|subelements('ipv4') }}"
  when:
    - item.1.address is defined
    - item.1.mask is defined
```

gives

```
"msg": "matched 4.4.4.4/8 on ae10"
```

Conditional output can be achieved also with the template below

```
{% for item in interfaces %}
{% for ip in item.ipv4 %}
{% if ip.address and ip.mask%}
            matched {{ ip.address }}/{{ ip.mask }} on {{ item.name }}
{% else %}
            nothing matched
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```